# Drawing only part of a texture OpenGL ES iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

[..Continued on from my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014352/fullscreen-texture-iphone-opengl-es)

I have a 320*480 RGB565 framebuffer which I wish to draw using OpenGL ES 1.0 on the iPhone.

```
- (void)setupView
{   
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, (int[4]){0, 0, 480, 320});

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

// Updates the OpenGL view when the timer fires
- (void)drawView
{
  // Make sure that you are drawing to the current context 
  [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

  //Get the 320*480 buffer
  const int8_t * frameBuf = [source getNextBuffer];

  //Create enough storage for a 512x512 power of 2 texture
  int8_t lBuf[2*512*512];

  memcpy (lBuf, frameBuf, 320*480*2);

  //Upload the texture
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, lBuf);

  //Draw it
  glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 1, 480, 320);

  [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}
```

If I produce the original texture in 512*512 the output is cropped incorrectly but other than that looks fine. However using the require output size of 320*480 everything is distorted and messed up.

I'm pretty sure it's the way I'm copying the framebuffer into the new 512*512 buffer. I have tried this routine

```
int8_t lBuf[512][512][2];
const char * frameDataP = frameData;
for (int ii = 0; ii < 480; ++ii) {
    memcpy(lBuf[ii], frameDataP, 320);
    frameDataP += 320;
}
```

Which is better, but the width appears to be stretched and the height is messed up.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you drawing this background in portrait or landscape mode? The `glDrawTexiOES` parameters are `(x, y, z, width, height)` and since every other part of your code seems to reference those numbers as `320x480` that might be contributing to the "cropped incorrectly" problem - try switching the `320` and `480` in the cropping rectangle and the width/height in the `glDrawTex` call. (Might be partially my fault here for not posting the parameters in the last thread. Sorry!)

You'll have to use that second FB copy routine though. The reason the `memcpy` command won't work is because it will grab the 320x480x2 buffer (307200 bytes) and dump it into a 512x512x2 buffer (524288 bytes) as a single contiguous block - it won't know enough to copy 320 bytes, add 192 blocks of "dead space", and resume.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the buffer allocated isn't large enough.  If you have 8 bits (1 byte) per color component, you are allocating one byte too few.  This could explain why the image shows correct for only a part of the image.
I would think the following lines:

```
 //Create enough storage for a 512x512 power of 2 texture
 int8_t lBuf[2*512*512];
 memcpy (lBuf, frameBuf, 320*480*2);
```

would need to be changed to:

```
 //Create enough storage for a 512x512 power of 2 texture
 int8_t lBuf[3*512*512];
 memcpy (lBuf, frameBuf, 320*480*3);
```

Comment: Ben's loading it as RGB565 (16bpp) - two bytes per pixel is correct.